# RxAndroidBle long write - callback for each batch written

Tags: rxandroidble

I'm doing a long write operation, sending 16 byte batches at a time. I'd like to have a progress bar show the progress of the long write to the user, so I need some sort of callback for each time a batch has been written.

From the documentation, it looked like `setWriteOperationAckStrategy` does this. However, when running the following code, I only end up seeing one message output to the log. What am I doing wrong here?

```
subscription = connection.flatMap(rxBleConnection -> rxBleConnection.createNewLongWriteBuilder()
    .setCharacteristicUuid(uuid)
    .setBytes(bytes)
    .setMaxBatchSize(16)
    .setWriteOperationAckStrategy(new RxBleConnection.WriteOperationAckStrategy() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Boolean> call(Observable<Boolean> booleanObservable) {
            Log.d("TEST", "batch written");
            return booleanObservable;
        }
    })
    .build()
```

Comment: Hey! The `setWriteOperationAckStrategy` is similar to standard RxJava's Observable transformers. In order to keep the allocation low, we tend to modify source observable rather than to create a new one when each batch is completed. I modified your post with a proposed test scenario.

Comment: That did it! You can post that as the answer and I'll mark it correct, if you like. Thanks! :)

Comment: Cool, I posted the code sample along with the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setWriteOperationAckStrategy is similar to standard RxJava's Observable transformers. In order to keep the allocation low, we tend to modify source observable rather than to create a new one when each batch is completed.

```
subscription = connection.flatMap(rxBleConnection -> rxBleConnection.createNewLongWriteBuilder()
    .setCharacteristicUuid(uuid)
    .setBytes(bytes)
    .setMaxBatchSize(16)
    .setWriteOperationAckStrategy(new RxBleConnection.WriteOperationAckStrategy() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Boolean> call(Observable<Boolean> booleanObservable) {
            Log.d("TEST", "batch written");
            return booleanObservable
                .doOnNext(new Action1<Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Boolean aBoolean) {
                        Log.d("TEST", "batch written");
                    }
                });
        }
    })
    .build()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this answer was for RxJava, for RxJava2 this is the updated lambda syntax:

```
.setWriteOperationAckStrategy(booleanObservable -> {
        Log.d("TEST", "batch written");
        return booleanObservable
            .doOnNext(aBoolean -> {
              Log.d("TEST", "batch written");
            });
      }
```

Full:

```
.setWriteOperationAckStrategy(new RxBleConnection.WriteOperationAckStrategy() {
  @Override
  public Observable<Boolean> apply(Observable<Boolean> booleanObservable) {
    Log.d("TEST", "batch written");
    return booleanObservable
        .doOnNext(new Consumer<Boolean>() {
           @Override
           public void accept(Boolean aBoolean) {
             Log.d("TEST", "batch written");
           }
         });
  }
```